# Is there a way for the Azure Activity Log to track changes to Tags?

Tags: azure, tags, activitylog

I cannot find any mention anywhere of tracking changes to Tags in Azure.
We just had a situation where all Tags vanished from a Resource Group and we have no idea why.
The Activity Logs show nothing related to Tags.
Any idea how to track changes to Tags on a resource?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
AzureActivity
| where OperationNameValue == "microsoft.resources/tags/write"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Frustratingly, the only information in there is who and when :-/